# How to put some words in italic or bold in a property list

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-text, nsattributedstring, property-list

If I have this text in a plist:

```
<string>The quick brown fox.</string>
```

How could I specify that "quick" should be italic and "fox" should be bold, both in the plist itself, and in the code that is displaying this text in a UILabel? I'm fine with solutions that work for iOS6 and up.

Answer (score 0):

The property list doesn't natively support this type of information. You would need to add a number of key/value pairs to represent this information. This could be in the form of an array containing dictionaries with keys for the range start and length and the format to apply to that range.

Alternatively, store the string as HTML in the property list...

Comment: Is there a way to define a custom format, such as "The *quick* brown fox", where any word enclosed in the asterisks could be made italic?

Comment: If you make up a format, sure. That's what I described. Or you could use HTML (i.e. tags in the string that you parse).